# Where to put the domain in MVCS

Tags: design-patterns, mvc

From what I've read and understand MVCS (Model-View-Controller-Store) is a design pattern that lets you do the following:

*View* - Application view, what the user will see.
*Controllers* - Manages the views and calls the models.
*Model* - Business logic.
*Stores* -  Calls to db for CRUD operations retrieving and putting data.

Now where should I put the domain in this design? By domain, I mean the actual classes that represents the objects from db for example a user. Should they be inside the model or in a different layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you come up with some specific code that changes my mind, I'm going to say that MVCS is just a slight variation on MVC that makes it clearer that the Business Domain lives in the Model, and is technically separate from the data Store.  MVC just includes S (the data store) as part of the Model, but the business domain always lives there.